# Unable to locate consul service with wildfly-swarm instance from wildfly-swarm-examples/ribbon-consul

Tags: consul, wildfly-swarm

Following instructions in [ribbon-consul example](https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples/tree/master/ribbon-consul) I started consul with

```
consul agent -dev
```

then in parent folder of this example

```
mvn verify -Pconsul  -Dswarm.consul.url=http://localhost:8500
```

From what I gather this is the default location of consul, so I also ran it without, only to have the same result.
Task eventually starts all services, however fails to register with consul, with output:

```
2017-08-25 16:54:00,324 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.runtime.deployer] (main) deploying time.war
2017-08-25 16:54:00,354 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "time.war" (runtime-name: "time.war")
2017-08-25 16:54:01,778 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.time.war" is using a private module ("io.netty:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
2017-08-25 16:54:01,923 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
2017-08-25 16:54:02,036 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service swarm.topology.register.time.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service swarm.topology.register.time.http: com.orbitz.consul.ConsulException: Invalid service address
    at org.wildfly.swarm.topology.deployment.RegistrationAdvertiser.start(RegistrationAdvertiser.java:79)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.orbitz.consul.ConsulException: Invalid service address
    at com.orbitz.consul.AgentClient.register(AgentClient.java:180)
    at com.orbitz.consul.AgentClient.register(AgentClient.java:184)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.topology.consul.runtime.Advertiser.advertise(Advertiser.java:65)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.topology.consul.runtime.ConsulTopologyConnector.advertise(ConsulTopologyConnector.java:60)
    at org.wildfly.swarm.topology.deployment.RegistrationAdvertiser.start(RegistrationAdvertiser.java:77)
    ... 5 more

2017-08-25 16:54:02,203 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.wildfly.swarm.generated.WildFlySwarmDefaultJAXRSApplication
2017-08-25 16:54:02,221 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /
2017-08-25 16:54:02,242 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: (("deployment" => "time.war")) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"swarm.topology.register.time.http" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service swarm.topology.register.time.http: com.orbitz.consul.ConsulException: Invalid service address
    Caused by: com.orbitz.consul.ConsulException: Invalid service address"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["swarm.topology.register.time.http"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
2017-08-25 16:54:02,244 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "time.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"swarm.topology.register.time.http" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service swarm.topology.register.time.http: com.orbitz.consul.ConsulException: Invalid service address
    Caused by: com.orbitz.consul.ConsulException: Invalid service address"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["swarm.topology.register.time.http"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
2017-08-25 16:54:02,250 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /
2017-08-25 16:54:02,254 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
2017-08-25 16:54:02,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment time.war (runtime-name: time.war) in 28ms
2017-08-25 16:54:02,273 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (main) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service swarm.topology.register.time.http

2017-08-25 16:54:02,275 ERROR [stderr] (main) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-08-25 16:54:02,275 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,275 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,275 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,275 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,275 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:39)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,276 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.main(MainInvoker.java:92)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,276 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"swarm.topology.register.time.http" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service swarm.topology.register.time.http: com.orbitz.consul.ConsulException: Invalid service address
2017-08-25 16:54:02,276 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: com.orbitz.consul.ConsulException: Invalid service address"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["swarm.topology.register.time.http"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
2017-08-25 16:54:02,276 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:301)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,276 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:174)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,276 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,277 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:467)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,277 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.examples.netflix.ribbon.time.Main.main(Main.java:19)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,277 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 6 more
2017-08-25 16:54:02,278 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"swarm.topology.register.time.http" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service swarm.topology.register.time.http: com.orbitz.consul.ConsulException: Invalid service address
2017-08-25 16:54:02,278 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: com.orbitz.consul.ConsulException: Invalid service address"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["swarm.topology.register.time.http"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
2017-08-25 16:54:02,278 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:296)
2017-08-25 16:54:02,278 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 10 more
```

This is repeated for every time and event service started. Frontend reports consul service at `http://:8300`.

Starting main methods from idea with offset will perform fine (tho frontend returns 403:forbidden, but that is an another issue)

Is there something I am missing, because this seems like a pretty simple example to be bugged?

Versions of examples affected are `2017.9.0-SNAPSHOT` and `2017.8.1`.

Comment: It might just be that no one has tried using it without setting the consul url directly.

Please raise an issue, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM, and we can look at it

Comment: I tried it both ways. Anyway thanks I'll add an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consul client exception "Invalid service address" indicates that service is being registered with IP "0.0.0.0". See [consul source code](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/agent/consul/catalog_endpoint.go)

By default, Swarm has default value "0.0.0.0" for "swarm.bind.address" property, which means accepting connections for “all interfaces” to Swarm.
It seems that this IP is being used to register service to consul.

Try to specify swarm.bind.address system property in test/pom.xml for every process e.g.

```
    <process>
        <artifactId>example-ribbon-consul-time</artifactId>
        <properties>
           <swarm.http.port>8081</swarm.http.port>
           <swarm.bind.address>127.0.0.1</swarm.bind.address>
        </properties>
    </process>
```